# how to open iframe by clicking a url

Tags: javascript, php

I need to open an iframe window by clicking on `ahref`. This is my code and I need to open link to `ahref` as an iframe.

Could anyone please help me to do that?

**Code:**

```
function selectRepair()
    {
          $this->content_jscript = <<<End_Of_String

End_Of_String;


        $data = graphsCreationSQL::getRepairList ();
        $reapirList = "";
        foreach ( $data as $row )
        {
            $reapirList .= "<a href='create-graphs-repair.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_reapirName}=$row->clientName'>$row->clientName</a></br>";
        }


        $this->content_html = <<<End_Of_String

                            {$reapirList}

End_Of_String;
    }
```

Comment: What is the "window" you need exactly? A popup window or an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure about whether or not this would work from the perspective of passing through the url, my basic javascript is a bit rusty, though you should hopefully be able to work out something that works in regards to that.

```
foreach ( $data as $row )
{
    $repairList .= "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"makeIFrame('create-graphs-repair.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_reapirName'}=$row->clientName)\">$row->clientName</a>"
}
```

Then in Javascript

```
function makeIFrame(url) { 
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
    iframe.setAttribute("src", url); 
    iframe.style.width = 640+"px"; 
    iframe.style.height = 480+"px"; 
    document.body.appendChild(iframe); 
}
```

Comment: use lowercase tag names please.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work for me.i need to open iframe by clicking the url.

Comment: @devuser I don't entirely get what you mean by "open the iframe by clicking the url". Do you need this to be on a separate page with an iframe inside it or should it appear on the page the user is on?

Comment: sorry for not writing it clearly.it is not on a separate page and need to  appear on the same page.

Comment: @devuser Ok, sorry then, this method worked for me, not entirely sure why it doesn't work for you. Do you get the links but nothing happens when they're clicked? If so you might want to re-write the `$repairList` line just to make sure that there wasn't a problem from copying the code across incorrectly. Or just post the output `<a>` tag here so we can check it.

Comment: Yes i'm getting the links but its not clickable.$reapirList .= "<a href='#' onclick=makeIFrame(create-graphs-repair.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_reapirName}=$row->clientName)>$row->clientName</a></br>";

Comment: @devuser I'm pretty sure you need quotations for the `onclick` and for the arguments to `makeIFrame()` like this: `$reapirList .= "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"makeIFrame(\'create-graphs-repair.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_ge‌​nerategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_reapirName}=$row->clientName\')\">$row->clientName</a></‌​br>"` Also be sure to double-check that you're escaping quotation marks and apostrophes properly. It's worth checking the source code of the output to make sure that the link looks as expected (i.e. `<a href="#" onclick="makeIFrame('url here')">link here</a>`)